# How to add custom comments

Tags: support

Not sure if this is the right place to ask...

I'm trying to get <kbd>[AutoReviewComment](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)</kbd> working but can't add own comments without overwriting the default ones, nor can I use the import function (doesn't add comments to the list of chooseables). I'm using chrome 46.0.2490.52 beta (64-bit).

It only shows

[image]

without a possibility to add a comment. When clicking on `import/export` I get this list

[image]

but can't add a comment to the select view.

How does it work?

Comment: Probably a question for Stack Apps, but I'm not even sure how active the site is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a user script that has a clearly defined help process in place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Short answer

You are probably better asking your question at [Github issue tracker](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments/issues).

---

#### Long answer

AutoReviewComments was originally hosted on Stack Apps (see [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)). This question now appears to be inactive.

However AutoReviewComments is now hosted on [GitHub (Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments)](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments)

> Please report new issues or feature requests on our issue tracker!
>
> The work on making this a full-blown Github based project originally outlined in this answer is now complete. All further feature requests and bug reports should be directed at the [Github issue tracker](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments/issues).

Source [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se)